# Nested For Loop - Why with the code written like this, do I get more asterix than println?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

```
int n = 10;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      System.out.print("*");
      System.out.println();
  }
```

Question says it really, was struggling with this task a bit, and I tried it this way and it works, but I cant quite figure out why, written like this, it looks like there would be the same amount of println statements as asterix (*) symbols. Which would obviously not make the desired triangle (It would just make a line as long as n). So the only way I can see why this works is by picturing another brace for the initial for loop with the println statement. I presume it is something I have forgotten about how the for loop executes its code. But Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

So is the code not better written like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {            
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because inner loop's body is just one *statement*

```
for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      System.out.print("*");
```

without brackets around

change it to

```
 for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
      System.out.print("*");
      System.out.println();
 }
```

or even you don't need second statement this way

```
 for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
      System.out.println("*");
 }
```

Comment: Ah right you are! Damn, should have remembered that from the while loop work! Thank you very much for your help sir!

Comment: *yes* readable + if you want new line printed after inner loop prints all the `*`